# posts array of all element names by class

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have numerous elements on a page. I am using Jquery toggle to toggle a class.
I need to post a php array containing the names of all the elements that contained that class. (were toggled on).

My first thought was to simply create an form with display:none with a listbox. Everytime the element is toggled the name will be added to the listbox and then when the user clicks next all the values from the listbox are posted to the next page. I am hoping that there might be a cleaner and simpler solution than this.

So, to clarify, I am wanting to detect all the elements that I toggled on, and post those values to another page.

How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to detect all the ones that were toggled on, even if they get toggled off, or only those that are toggled on at the time of clicking next?

Comment: Only those that are toggled on at the time of clicking next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of all the element names (is this the `name` attribute, or the `id`) with the `.map()` function:

```
var names = $(".targetClassName").map(function() {
    return this.name; //takes the `name` attribute, change to `id` for ID
}).get();
```

Comment: Haven't try it yet, but it looks like that might be what I am after. Thanks